# How get relation with pivot table?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a tables:

categories - this is vehicle categories

[image]

dicts_groups - i have a lot of things there

[image]

dicts - for my dict groups i see what is body type(s)

[image]

category_dict_group - pivot table

[image]

My category class

```
public function bodyTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\DictGroup');
    }
```

this is my dictGroup class

```
public function dicts() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Dict');
   }
```

I want get all body parts for category = 1 so my code is simple now:

```
dd(Category::find(1)->bodyTypes()->pluck('id'));
```

result is

```
Collection {#248 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => 7
  ]
}
```

which is ok cause 7 is my dict_group_id from pivot table i think. How can i get body type list from dict ? like what i need add to function bodyTypes to get list like from table DICTS (id, symbol, public_name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with()` to eager load the relations:

```
dd(Category::with('bodyTypes', 'bodyTypes.dicts')->find(1)->bodyTypes);
```

This should return you all the `bodyTypes` with the `dicts` relation loaded.

The following should give you a collection of all dicts:

```
$c = Category::with('bodyTypes', 'bodyTypes.dicts')->find(1);
dd($c->bodyTypes->pluck('dicts'));
```

Comment: seems like it is relations but i dont know how can i get vale from dict table now. Would u like see screen of results what relations i have now ?

Comment: I updated my answer with how you can get a collection of all dicts.